# Dynamically Create the Expression of a List Comprehension

Tags: python

I have a bunch of AWS Lambda functions in Python that retrieve data from an API and write it to CSV. After I retrieve the data, I extract the relevant fields I want using list comprehensions, something like:

```
records = requests.get(url,headers,params)
values = [(x['id'],x['name'],x['address']) for x in records]
```

This works well. However, I have other types of records (from API calls to different URLs) that I retrieve in this way:

```
values = [(x['orders'][0]['status'],x['assignee']['id']) for x in records]
```

Is there any way I can build those list comprehensions dynamically? I would like to be able to use one script that takes in a url and some other input information, then pass in an "expression", and create a list comprehension that extract the information I want from the data that the API returns.

I was not able to find a way to use parameters in the list comprehension.

Comment: Why? The expression is most of it already, is removing the simple little `for x in records]` really that helpful?

Comment: If you can write it as a series of separate lines (with `for` and `if` statements), then you can write it as a comprehension.  Although if it is working with separate statements, it's not clear why you would worry about it.

Comment: The idea is I can use the same script for several (in my case, about a dozen) use-cases, and I can just pass it the pattern that I want to use to extract data. Then I can use one AWS Lambda function instead of several

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditionals in the list comprehension. While I don't know what particularly you'd like to condition on, it would look something like this:

```py
values = [(x['id'],x['name'],x['address']) if <CONDITION> else (x['orders'][0]['status'],x['assignee']['id']) for x in records]
```

Though this is not very legible. One way to fix this is to use helper functions:

```py
def model1(x: Dict):
    return (x['id'],x['name'],x['address'])

def model2(x: Dict):
    return (x['orders'][0]['status'],x['assignee']['id'])

def condition(x: Dict):
    return True # TODO: fill out with whatever condition you want 

values = [model1(x) if condition(x) else model2(x) for x in records]
```

Comment: This worked beautifully and was fairly simple to implement - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have simple non-nested fields in the data the Python item getter might be the solution. For example (assuming that JSON is the format for the response):

```py
import requests
from operator import itemgetter

def fetch_data(url, headers, params, fields):
    records = requests.get(url, headers, params).json()
    getter = itemgetter(*fields)
    values = [getter(record) for record in records]
    return values
```

But for nested objects a custom function might be the solution:

```py
def get_nested_field(data, field):
    # Split the field by '.' and iterate over each section
    for section in field.split('.'):
        # If the section represents a list index, convert it to an integer
        if section.endswith(']') and section[:-1].isdigit():
            data = data[int(section[:-1])]
        # Otherwise, treat it as a dictionary key
        else:
            data = data[section]
    return data

def fetch_data(url, headers, params, fields):
    records = requests.get(url, headers, params).json()

    values = [[get_nested_field(record, field) for field in fields] for record in records]

    return values
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be easy if you didn't had nested lists/dicts in your records:

```
def parametric_lc(records, rkeys):
    return [[rec[rk] for rk in rkeys] for rec in records]

rkeys1 = ['id','name','address']
records1 = [{'id':1,'name':'alice','address':'here'},
            {'id':2,'name':'bob','address':'there'}]
rkeys2 = ['status','assignee']
records2 = [{'status':'open','assignee':1},
            {'status':'closed','assignee':2}]

print(parametric_lc(records1, rkeys1))
[[1, 'alice', 'here'], [2, 'bob', 'there']]

print(parametric_lc(records2, rkeys2))
[['open', 1], ['closed', 2]]
```

However, handling different levels of nesting would require some much more complicated code, and I don't know whether it is worth the effort. If you really want to do it then you may consider the above code as a hint :)

Comment: It is. But I would not know how to use `itemgetter` when we want to handle nested data, so why to use it in what was meant as an example of how the OP's request can be satisfied?